# How to return this data to component from promise in provider

Tags: angular, typescript

The code below shows my call in the component.

The `getLocations` is in the `provider`.

I am failing to understand how to get the data back to the component to display to the user. I can see the data in the format `[{},{}]` in the console but need to access use it on the front end.

I am very new to angular and this is my first attempt at an HTTP call using `component/provider/promise`.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Is this best practice for Angular 5? Sorry for my ignorance.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public loginProvider: LoginProvider, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

        this.loginProvider.getLocations();
  }

getLocations() {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let apiURL = 'http://xxxx-dev.xxxxxxx.com/api/default/v1/locations';
       this.http.get(apiURL)
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        res => { // Success

          this.locations = res.json(); 
          console.log(this.locations);
          resolve();                

        }
      );
  });
  return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First , you need to resolve the data in promise, like below:

```
// Promise provide two executors for normal and exception branches
new Promise(resolve, reject)

// if you are using HttpClient instead of Http, you don't need to call .json method
resolve(res.json());  
// for throwing err
reject(new Error('sample err'))
```

Then you can get the result data in `then` of promise, like below:

```
this.loginProvider.getLocations().then(result => {
  // result is the data you resolved in promise
  // do things based on result 
}).catch(err => {
  // deal with exceptions
})
```

For more about promise, refer **[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)**.

Comment: This appears to have worked. How do I handle in the promise 404, 405, etc errors? and pass them back to the component in order to pop up alerts?

Comment: @JoeStarnes for exceptions, you can use `catch` from promise. see my updated answer. BTW, if you create a new promise, you need to use `reject` from promise to throw exceptions yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to explicitly create a new promise when you're already using the toPromise() call.
I would use something like this:

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
   this.locations = await this._getLocations();
}

private _getLocations(): Promise<Location[]> {
   return this._http.get<LocationReturnData>(apiUrl).toPromise().then(res => res);
}
```

async and await are just shorthand for handling promises. await will WAIT for the return on the promise before going to the next line of code and it requires the async handler. It's much shorter & simpler than stacking then()'s.

I didn't see injection for http but I'm assuming you're using the latest HttpClient, which should handle any json data for you by default.

Answer (score 0):

if you need result of request in other method call, you should just return it in onfulfilled(success) function, like this:

```
    getLocations() {
         let apiURL = 'http://xxxx-dev.xxxxxxx.com/api/default/v1/locations';
         return   this.http.get(apiURL)
          .toPromise()
          .then(
            (success) => { 
              this.locations = res.json(); 
              console.log(this.locations);

              return success;          
            }
          );
    }

    otherMethod() {
        getLocations().then(
            (res) => {
                //you see result of query that returned in http request
            }
        );
    }
}
```